# Small and large adverbs

Tags: adverbs

On the mathematics stackexchange site, [I wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389891/how-to-prove-an-asymmetric-voting-system-with-99-9-success-rate-cannot-be-beate):

> If you are certain that those earlier in the order will collectively reach a correct decision then you weight your vote so *small* that you do not affect the collective vote, while if you are not certain then you weight your vote so *large* that it will overwhelm the votes of all those earlier in the order.

For reasons I cannot quite explain, I am not comfortable with the use of *small* and *large* there.  I could have used *lightly* and *heavily*, which are adverbs, but I felt that would have been pushing the weighting metaphor further than is usual in this mathematical sense.  But *smally* and *smallly* are not words, while *largely* means something more like *mostly*. I would not use the Trumpian *big-league* or *bigly* and presumably *little-league* or *littlely*.

I could have rewritten this to something like "... you give your vote a weight which is so small that ...", but my question here is about whether there are adverbs directly  corresponding to *small* and *large*.

Comment: Use _size_ instead of _weight_; the extra metaphor (gravity is not actually involved here) adds extra conditions.

Comment: How about 'tiny' and 'great'?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your question is here . . . Are you asking why small and large don't work here?  Grammatically they do.  Stylisitically you're mixing metaphors weight and size.  Are you asking which is better light/heavy vs small/large?  B/c that's POB.  Overall, weighting your vote should probably follow light/heavy only b/c it's the same metaphor.  But, that's my opinion.

Comment: @DavidM I am indeed in part asking if *small* and *large* are adverbs and can as such here.  I did in fact do so, but did not feel comfortable when I did

Comment: insignificantly and substantially

Answer (score 1):

weight your vote so LIGHTLY. weight your vote so HEAVILY.

That's not overdoing it, it's English.

Or rewrite it.

Comment: Hi Fred, welcome ELU.  This answer is not quite what we prefer on this type of site.  Rather, we'd expect an explanation for why you feel that these are preferable to the OP's original choices.  Preferably this would also include some sort of reference where possible.

Comment: OP does say in the question that these terms were considered, but they are not right.